# Divisibility criterion exercise

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 \leq n \leq 1000$.

1. How many of them are divisible by 9?
2. Using one of the divisibility criterion by 9, confirm the answer that you've adquired on the previous item.

For 1, I thought that a number is divisible by 9 if it has the form $9k, k \in \mathbb{N}$. So we have:
$$0 \leq 9k \leq 1000 \implies 0 \leq k \leq \frac{1000}{9}$$

So we have $112$ natural numbers between $0$ and $1000$ that are divisible by $9$. (is that right?)

For 2, the only divisibility criterion by $9$ I know is that the sum of all digits must be divisible by $9$, but I don't know how to apply it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your answer, and your analysis.

Alternative approach:

In every sequence of $n$ consecutive integers, exactly $1$ of them is divisible by $n$.

Therefore, in every sequence of $9$ consecutive integers, exactly $1$ of them is divisible by $9$.  Therefore, there are exactly $(111)$ numbers in the set $\{1,2,\cdots,999\}$ that are divisible by $(9)$.

You add $(+1)$, since, on the front end, $(0)$ is divisible by $(9)$, and you note that at the tail end, $(1000)$ is not divisible by $(9)$.

Unclear what divisibility by $(9)$ criterion you've  been taught.  The only one that I know about is *casting out* $(9)$'s, which basically means that $n$ is divisible by $(9)$ if and only if the sum of the digits of $(n)$ is divisible by $(9)$.  I do not see how *casting out* $(9)$'s can be readily used to verify the answer of $(112).$